# How validate XML with XSD, when part of validation rules are in WSDL

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xsd, wsdl

I use C#, .NET 4.5, Console application.
I added WSDL file in service reference. Inside WSDL are validation rules like:

```
<xs:complexType name="xRequest">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="SenderDateTime" type="ip:grDateTime"/>
    <xs:element name="SenderId" type="ip:grIdentifier"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

There is XSD file too, with details of validation rules like:

```
<xs:simpleType name="grDateTime">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4,4}\-[0-9]{2,2}\-[0-9]{2,2}[T][0-9]{2,2}:[0-9]{2,2}:[0-9]{2,2}(\.[0-9]{1,6}){0,1}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And I have automatically generated properties from WSDL in Reference.cs like:

```
public partial class xRequest
{
    private string senderIdField;
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public string SenderId {
        get {
            return this.senderIdField;
        }
        set {
            this.senderIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("SenderId");
        }
    }
}
```

I serialize xRequest object into XML and I want to validate it.
How can I validate XML with XSD, when part of validation rules are in WSDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as straight forward as it should be... Look at this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647820.aspx) (Step 4, 5 and 11), I think it is essentially what you want to do (client side) but it also shows how to do the validation server side.